# How do I escape % in Knex where like query?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, knex.js

I'm using `knex` to generate my SQL queries. In `knex` documentation, it shows this

```
knex('users').where('columnName', 'like', '%rowlikeme%')
```

Now in my application, I did this:

```
function search(term) {
  term = "%" + term + "%";
  knex('table').where('description', 'like', term);
  // ...
}
```

How can I escape `%` so that it searches for `%` as part of the term as well?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

For this case I use

rather string interpolation from `es6` (safe version)

```
knex('table').where('description', 'like', `%${term}%`)
```

or `??` parameter [binding](http://knexjs.org/#Raw-Bindings)

```
knex('table').whereRaw('description like \'%??%\'', [term])
```

But in the first case, you must be 100% sure that term is valid, because of the [possibility of SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49665379/3884290).

Comment: The _first_ example has the possibility of SQL injection. The second is using named parameters, so should be safe.

Comment: The first one does not work for me. When term is 'foo' the binding is 'undefinedfooundefined'.

Comment: @user128216 Why is the first example `where('description', 'like', `%${term}%`)` prone sql injection? Isn't this as safe as the parameter binding? The ref link doesn't mention where being prone to sql injection, only raw.

Comment: The term in a `.where` is escaped, so there's no risk of injection: https://github.com/knex/documentation/issues/73#issuecomment-572482153

Comment: The second one is badly wrong and shouldn't work at all (`??` binding should be used only for identifiers, so if there is dot in `term` it will fail). First one should be fine except I have no idea if that actually is able to match `%` char.

Answer (score 5):

So I was looking for a correct way to apply LOWER function to the parameter. Here's the solution that seems to be working fine for me:

```
builder.whereRaw('LOWER(last_name) LIKE LOWER(?)', [`%${lastName}%`])
```

Answer (score 2):

@coockoo's answer is incorrect for both of the SQLs. Their first one would still allow `%` through as Knex does not escape `%` for `LIKE` operations. The second SQL simply does not work as Knex **wraps the bound value with quotes**.

The correct way should be

```js
const term = '10%'
const b = knex('table').where('description', 'like', `%${term.replaceAll('%', '\\%')}%`)
```

The output of `b.toString()` is:

```sql
select * from "table" where "description" like E'%10\\%%'
```

Postgres will interpret `E'\\%'` as `'\%'`, which is an escaped percentage sign according to: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-LIKE by default if you are on newer Postgres version.

---

This can be verified with this table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test (
    description character varying(256)
);

INSERT INTO test VALUES ('a%b');
```

and test the following:

1. Without escaping `%` like others have suggested. This **shouldn't work**.

```js
knex('test').where('description', 'like', 'a%%%b').toString()
```

```sql
select * from "test" where "description" like 'a%%%b'
```

```
 description
-------------
 a%b
(1 row)
```

2. Escaping `%` before giving to Knex.

   1. This should return no rows:

   ```js
   knex('test').where('description', 'like', 'a\\%\\%\\%b').toString()
   ```

   ```sql
   select * from "test" where "description" like E'a\\%\\%\\%b'
   ```

   ```
    description
   -------------
   (0 rows)
   ```

   2. This should return `'a%b'`:

   ```js
   knex('test').where('description', 'like', 'a\\%b').toString()
   ```

   ```sql
   select * from "test" where "description" like E'a\\%b'
   ```

   ```
    description
   -------------
    a%b
   (1 row)
   ```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/d2f5e/1

Answer (score 0):

Use the RLIKE instead of LIKE as below, It should work for you.

```
function search(term){
    knex('table').where('description','rlike',term);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Hi, rlike didn't pass the test case. Example: Search term is "40%".
Result should show: "Microscopic 40% Bacterialium", "40% Alcohol", "Creatine 40%" But it is not showing "Creatine 40%" and "Microscopic 40% Bacterialium".

Comment: Can you try papssing term once with "  `  " as : 
     knex('table').where('description','like',`term`);

Comment: If i add % before and after the term, it will reply all 3 three results. If I don't, it will return nothing while using like keyword.

Comment: Because, that is the rule of like. For example if you have a value like "World" and search for '%orl%' with like then it will return. but if you search for 'orl' with then it won't. Here '%' mean one or more character

Answer (score 0):

Knex doesn't have an equivalent to the `ESCAPE` keyword [1], so you have to do a raw query like this, which will search for users with `name === "%foo%"`:

```
knex.raw('select * from users where name like ? escape \', ['\%foo\%'])
```

And this, with an unescaped wildcard at the beginning of the search term, will search for users with `name` ending in `"%foo%"`:

```
knex.raw('select * from users where name like ? escape \', ['%\%foo\%'])
```

[1] Closed feature request: https://github.com/knex/knex/issues/648

Comment: By reading SQL docs this kind of make sense and could work. Though `knex('users').whereRaw('?? like ? escape \\%, ['name', '%\\%foo%'])` might be more near to working solution.

Answer (score 0):

whereILike

http://knexjs.org/guide/query-builder.html#whereilike

This is doc for this

```js
knex('users').whereILike('email', '%mail%')

knex('users')
  .whereILike('email', '%MAIL%')
  .andWhereILike('email', '%.COM')
  .orWhereILike('email', '%NAME%')
```

Answer (score 0):

For this to resolve you can add the search term in a separate variable and add % at the beginning and end of the string.
For ex:

```
const likeParams = '%' + selectedKeyword + '%';
knex('users').where('title', 'ilike', likeParams);
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is 2 years old, but reading the Knex documentation I found out they added a function for this scenario.

```js
knex('users').whereLike('email', '%mail%');
```

Answer (score -1):

Hey have you tried this

```
knex('Quotes').where('quoteBody', 'like', **'%'+Quote+'%'**)
```

just the regular javascript escaping works just fine.

Answer (score -3):

I have not used knex in a while so I can not test this. But have you tried to literally escape %? I hope that is what you want.

```
let term = "%something%"
let parsedTerm = term.replace("%", "\%")
console.log(parsedTerm);
```

Tell me about that please.