# Is knex.where prone to sql injection attacks?

Tags: javascript, sql, knex.js

This is a follow up question to https://stackoverflow.com/a/50337990/1370984 .

It mentions `knex('table').where('description', 'like', '%${term}%')` as prone to sql injection attacks. Even a comment mentions the first case as prone to injection attacks. Yet the reference provided never mentions `.where` being prone to injection attacks.

Is this a mistake? Why would knex allow `.where` to be prone to injection attacks but not `.whereRaw('description like \'%??%\'', [term])` . Aren't the arguments being parameterized in both cases?

Comment: @tadman This is a real issue? I looked at knex's `where` documentation and it doesn't mention it being sql injection prone. http://knexjs.org/#Builder-where In fact, the only mention of sql injection attacks is for `Raw` - http://knexjs.org/#Raw . This is concerning. What other features of knex are prone to sql injection attacks?

Comment: Knex maintenance here. Hi! I just wanted to mention also here that the premises of this question are all `false` and please ignore @tadman's comments here. One should not even use `??` binding in this case. **tl;dr fake news**

Comment: @MikaelLepistö Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> This is a follow up question to https://stackoverflow.com/a/50337990/1370984 .
>
> It mentions knex('table').where('description', 'like', '%${term}%') as prone to sql injection attacks. Even a comment mentions the first case as prone to injection attacks. Yet the reference provided never mentions .where being prone to injection attacks.

I'm knex maintainer and I have commented there that

```
knex('table').where('description', 'like', `%${term}%`)
```

is NOT vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.

> Is this a mistake? Why would knex allow .where to be prone to injection attacks but not .whereRaw('description like \'%??%\'', [term]) . Aren't the arguments being parameterized in both cases?

That `.whereRaw` is vulnerable when you interpolate values directly to sql string (like for example ?? identifier replacement does).

Correct use for `.whereRaw` in this case would be for example:

```
.whereRaw("?? like '%' || ? || '%'", ['description', term])
```

Where all identifiers are quoted correctly and `term` is sent to DB as parameter binding.

So the answer and most of the comments added to that answer are just plain wrong.